# railsでNo route matches [POST] "/posts/39/comments/41"と出てしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsでカウントした数を表示させたいのですが、No route matches [POST] "/posts/39/comments/41"と出てしまいます。

お力お貸しください。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

---

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'static_pages/about'

  get 'static_pages/privacy'

  get 'static_pages/agreement'

  get 'static_pages/organization'

  delete 'users', to: 'users#destroy'

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :activate
    end
  end

    get 'registrations/new'
  resource :registrations, only: [:new, :create]
  resource :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resource :settings, only: [:edit, :update]
  get 'settings/static_pages/about', to:'static_pages#about'
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :new]
  root to: 'posts#index'
  resources :users
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
      resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
  resources :genres
  get 'attensions', to:'attensions#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

showのビュー

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="answer">
      <h4>回答</h4>
      <% if @post.comments.any? %>
      <ul>
        <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
          <% if @post.user == comment.user %>
            <% if @post.situation? %>
              <p>質問者</p>
            <% else %>
              <p>質問者：<%= @post.user %></p>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            <p>回答者：<%= @post.user.name %></p>
          <% end %>
      <li>
        <%= comment.body %>
        <% if @post.user == current_user %>
          <%= link_to '回答を削除する',
            post_comment_path(@post, comment),
            method: :delete,
            class: 'command',
            data: {confirm: '回答を削除しますか?' } %>
        <% end %>
      </li>  
        <div class="evalation">
          <% if current_user.already_liked?(@post) %>
            <%= button_to '♡', post_comment_path(@post,comment), method: :update, class: "button"  %><%= comment.Evaluation %>
          <% else %>
            <% if comment.likes.count == 0 %>
              <%= button_to '♡', post_comment_path(@post,comment), method: :update, class: "button"%>
            <% else %>
              <%= button_to '♡', post_comment_path(@post,comment), name: "promote", class: "button"%><%= comment.Evaluation %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
      <% end %> 
      <%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.text_field :body, class: "show-content" %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.submit "回答する", class: "comment" %>
      </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @post.comments.create(comment_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)) 
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    def update
        if params[:promote] then
            @post.comments.increment!(:Evaluation, by = 0)
            @post.comments.touch
            redirect_to post_comment_path(@post,@comment)
        end
    end

    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
        end
            # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_comment
            @post.comments = Comment.find(params[:id])
        end

end
```

rails routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                    users#destroy
              activate_user GET    /users/:id/activate(.:format)                            users#activate
                            GET    /users(.:format)                                         users#index
                            POST   /users(.:format)                                         users#create
                   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                     users#new
                  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                users#edit
                       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#show
                            PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#update
                            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#update
                            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#destroy
                                      users#index
                            GET    /users/new(.:format)                                     users#new
                            GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#show
                       root GET    /                                                        posts#index
                            GET    /users(.:format)                                         users#index
                            POST   /users(.:format)                                         users#create
                            GET    /users/new(.:format)                                     users#new
                            GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                users#edit
                            GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#show
                            PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#update
                            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#update
                            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#destroy
         post_comment_likes POST   /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/likes(.:format)     likes#create
          post_comment_like DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/likes/:id(.:format) likes#destroy
              post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                       comments#index
                            POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                       comments#create
           new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)                   comments#new
          edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)              comments#edit
               post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#show
                            PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#update
                            PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#update
                            DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#destroy
                      posts GET    /posts(.:format)                                         posts#index
                            POST   /posts(.:format)                                         posts#create
                   new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                                     posts#new
                  edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                                posts#edit
                       post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                                     posts#show
                            PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                                     posts#update
                            PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                                     posts#update
                            DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                                     posts#destroy
                     genres GET    /genres(.:format)
```

Answer (score 0):

`post_comment_path`ではなく`post_comment_likes`に置き換えてみてください。